# Django2: Submit and store blobs as image files

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, blob

I have made a few Django projects after having read the tutorial but I am by no means an expert in Django.

I am trying to take a screenshot of the current page and store it (if one does not exist).

To achieve this, we require a few things:

1. function to get screen shot of current page
2. function to async post this image to a view which should store it
3. view that stores the posted image

However, the screen shot function results in a Blob and I am having trouble getting a Django view to properly handle this.

A demo project is available here: https://gitlab.com/SumNeuron/so_save_blob

## Function for screenshot

```js
const screenshot = (function() {
  function urlsToAbsolute(nodeList) {
      if (!nodeList.length) {
          return [];
      }
      var attrName = 'href';
      if (nodeList[0].__proto__ === HTMLImageElement.prototype
      || nodeList[0].__proto__ === HTMLScriptElement.prototype) {
          attrName = 'src';
      }
      nodeList = [].map.call(nodeList, function (el, i) {
          var attr = el.getAttribute(attrName);
          if (!attr) {
              return;
          }
          var absURL = /^(https?|data):/i.test(attr);
          if (absURL) {
              return el;
          } else {
              return el;
          }
      });
      return nodeList;
  }
  function addOnPageLoad_() {
      window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (e) {
          var scrollX = document.documentElement.dataset.scrollX || 0;
          var scrollY = document.documentElement.dataset.scrollY || 0;
          window.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);
      });
  }
  function capturePage(){
    urlsToAbsolute(document.images);
    urlsToAbsolute(document.querySelectorAll("link[rel='stylesheet']"));
    var screenshot = document.documentElement.cloneNode(true);
    var b = document.createElement('base');
    b.href = document.location.protocol + '//' + location.host;
    var head = screenshot.querySelector('head');
    head.insertBefore(b, head.firstChild);
    screenshot.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    screenshot.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    screenshot.style.webkitUserSelect = 'none';
    screenshot.style.mozUserSelect = 'none';
    screenshot.style.msUserSelect = 'none';
    screenshot.style.oUserSelect = 'none';
    screenshot.style.userSelect = 'none';
    screenshot.dataset.scrollX = window.scrollX;
    screenshot.dataset.scrollY = window.scrollY;
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.textContent = '(' + addOnPageLoad_.toString() + ')();';
    screenshot.querySelector('body').appendChild(script);
    var blob = new Blob([screenshot.outerHTML], {
        type: 'text/html'
    });
    return blob;
  }

  return capturePage
})()
```

## Function to async post Blob

```js
function setupAjaxWithCSRFToken() {
  // using jQuery
  var csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
  function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
      // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
      return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
  }
  // set csrf header
  $.ajaxSetup({
      beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
          if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
          }
      }
  });

}

function asyncSubmitBlob( url, blob ) {
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('image', blob);
  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "POST",
      data: fd,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(response){ console.log(response) },
      error: function(data){ console.log(data) }
  })
}
```

---

So to submit a screenshot of the current page:

```js
setupAjaxWithCSRFToken()
const page = window.location.pathname;
const blob_url = "{% url 'my-app:post_blob' 'REPLACE' %}".replace(/REPLACE/,page == '/' ? '' : page)
asyncSubmitBlob( blob_url, screenshot() )
```

## View to store the posted blob image

**urls.py**

```
...
from django.urls import include, path
...
app_name='my-app'
url_patterns=[
  ...
  path('post_blob/', views.post_blob, {'page':'/'},name='post_blob'),
  path('post_blob/<page>', views.post_blob,name='post_blob'),
  ...
]
```

**views.py**

```
from .models import PageBlob
...
def post_blob(request, page):
    if request.FILES: # save screenshot of specified page
        try:

            pb = PageBlob.objects.all().filter(page=page))
            if not pb.count():
                pb = PageBlob()
                pb.page = page
                pb.blob = request.FILES['image']
                pb.save()


                return HttpResponse('Blob Submitted')
        except:
            return HttpResponse('[App::my-app]\tError when requesting page_image({page})'.format(page=page))
    else: # return screenshot of requested page
        try:
            # get objects storing screenshot for requested page
            pb = PageBlob.objects.all().filter(page=page)
            # if one exists
            if pb.count():
                pb = pb[0]

                ## this just returns the string literal "blob"
                return HttpResponse(str(pb.blob))


            return HttpResponse('[App::my-app]\tNo blob for {page}'.format(page=page))
        except:
            return HttpResponse('[App::my-app]\tError when trying to retrieve blob for {page}'.format(page=page))
    return HttpResponse('Another response')
```

**models.py**

```
class PageBlob(models.Model):
    page = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    blob = models.TextField(db_column='data', blank=True)
```

But I can not seem to faithfully capture and retrieve the blob.

Many S.O. questions of storing blobs use the model approach with `import base64` to encode and decode the blob. One even recommends using the `BinaryField`. However, Django's documentation states firmly that `BinaryField` is not a replacement for the handling of static files.

So how could I achieve this?

S.O. posts I have found helpful to get this far

- [Upload an image blob from Ajax to Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48097297/upload-an-image-blob-from-ajax-to-django)
- [How to screenshot website in JavaScript client-side / how Google did it? (no need to access HDD)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621907/how-to-screenshot-website-in-javascript-client-side-how-google-did-it-no-nee)
- [How to download data in a blob field from database in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923139/how-to-download-data-in-a-blob-field-from-database-in-django)
- [passing blob parameter to django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571348/passing-blob-parameter-to-django)
- [Returning binary data with django HttpResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22276518/returning-binary-data-with-django-httpresponse)
- https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1597/
- [Django Binary or BLOB model field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064197/django-binary-or-blob-model-field)
- [Django CSRF check failing with an Ajax POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100539/django-csrf-check-failing-with-an-ajax-post-request)
- [How can javascript upload a blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333378/how-can-javascript-upload-a-blob)

Comment: It's unclear exactly what in this pipelin you need help fixing. Your blob data seems to be `text/html`, not an image.   `var blob = new Blob([screenshot.outerHTML], {
        type: 'text/html'
    });`

Comment: @HåkenLid well it is the text of the html nodes...

Comment: Why use blob for text? You can render the site to and image client side using https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas . Note that the resulting screenshot might look different than in the browser.

Comment: @HåkenLid when I tried it, it only took screen shot of that which fit within the view of the browser (not overflow) and I would like overflow. Perhaps that has changed...